# Importing tif image from PostgreSQL Database to webpage

Tags: python, postgresql, javascript

I am trying to import tif images from PostgreSQL Database to my website. In the website, I need to make a button control which will open the images. I think I have to use Python as a server side language and Ajax as well.

Does anyone know how I can connect to the database by using that button?

I already put/export my tif images into the PostgreSQL Database by raster2pgsql command.

My python script which I am planning to use for this button  is below: When I run this script, I can not see anything.

```
import psycopg2

def connect_db():

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgis_21_sample' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='elbasit99'")
        conn.set_session(autocommit=True)
        return conn
    except:
        print "I am unable to connect to the database"
        return None

def get_raster(raster_id,conn):
    query = "SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from node where id={}".format(raster_id)
    conn.cursor().execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchall()

    return res[0] [0]
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take our [Tour]. Is there a GIS component to your question?  To me it looks more suited to [su] or [dba.se].